# How to use require (webpack) with dynamic string, angularjs

Tags: angularjs, webpack

```
export function triMenuItemDirective() {
      var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^triMenu',
        scope: {
          item: '='
        },
        // replace: true,
        template: require('./menu-item-dropdown.tmpl.html'),
        controller: triMenuItemController,
        controllerAs: 'triMenuItem',
        bindToController: true
      };
      return directive;
    }
```

I need to load different html depending on `item`.

With the old way you could do:

```
template: '<div ng-include="::triMenuItem.item.template"></div>',
```

And in Controller

```
triMenuItem.item.template = 'app/components/menu/menu-item-' + triMenuItem.item.type + '.tmpl.html';
```

How do I achive this with webpack?

Something like

```
template: require('./menu-item-{{triMenuItem.item.type}}.tmpl.html'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that to do this, you have at least three different approaches:

**1- Use `$templateCache` and then pass a string variable to `ng-include`**

```
.directive('myDirective', ['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
    return {
        scope: {
            item: '='
        },
        template: '<div ng-include="content"></div>',
        link: function (scope) {
            $templateCache.put('a.tpl.html', require('./a.html'));
            $templateCache.put('b.tpl.html', require('./b.html'));

            scope.content = (scope.item === 'a') ? 'a.tpl.html' : 'b.tpl.html';
        }
    }

}]);
```

**2- Use `ng-bind-html`**.

```
app.directive('myDirective', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return {
        scope: {
            item: '='
        },
        template: '<div ng-bind-html="content"></div>',
        link: function (scope) {
            if(scope.item === 'a')
                scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(require('./a.html'));
        }
    }

}]);
```

**3- Use `ng-if`. Maybe the less dynamic solution of the three, but is pretty simple if your requirements let you do it.**

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            bool: '='
        },
        template: `
            <div>
                <div ng-if="item === 'a'">${require('./a.html')}</div>
                <div ng-if="item === 'b'">${require('./b.html')}</div>
            </div>
        `
    }

});
```